# How can I add a value to a tag in an XML-like file from within a BASH script?

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file called `metadata.xml` with the (unique) tag `MissingVal`, among many others:

**metadata.xml:**

```
<foo1>
    someData
</foo1>
<foo2>
    123.54
</foo2>
<MissingValue>

</MissingValue>
<foo3>
    1.0
</foo3>
```

I am using a BASH script to process this file. In the script I set the variable `SomeVal` to a numeric "real" value: `SomeVal=1234567890.0`.

How can I make my BASH script write the value of `SomeVal` to the `<MissingValue>` tag in the `metadata.xml` file? Running the script should make `metadata.xml` look like the following:

**metadata.xml:**

```
<foo1>
    someData
</foo1>
<foo2>
    123.54
</foo2>
<MissingValue>
    1234567890.0
</MissingValue>
<foo3>
    1.0
</foo3>
```

I imagine I could use `awk` or `sed` to do this, but I'm not familiar enough with these programs to make much headway.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure there is a beautiful method to do this with shell. Use some tools instead, like `libxml` in c++, or `ElementTree` in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sh$ export SomeVal=1234567890.0
sh$ perl \
     -0pe \
     "s|<MissingValue>\s*</MissingValue>|<MissingValue>$SomeVal</MissingValue>|sg" \
     metadata.xml
```

Producing:

```
<foo1>
    someData
</foo1>
<foo2>
    123.54
</foo2>
<MissingValue>1234567890.0</MissingValue>
<foo3>
    1.0
</foo3>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! 

What I ended up using was almost that -- I added newlines and redirected it to the same file: 
`cat metadata.xml | perl -0pe "s|<MissingValue>\s*</MissingValue>|<MissingValue>\\n$SomeVal\\n</MissingValue>|sg" >> metadata.xml`

Comment: You should not use `cat` with programs that can read data themself, like `perl` `awk` `sed` etc

Comment: @Jotne Of course. I use `cat` (more or less systematically) in order to clearly show the flow of data. Using a stdin redirection (`<`) is less readable when you are not accustomed to shell programming as it "hides" the source on the right-side on the expression -- whereas it feels more natural to have the source on the left and the destination on the right (as this is implied by the _pipe_ syntax). I understand one might disagree with that though.

Comment: All the senior here will say the same as I do.  It uses more resource, and will slow it down.  And you will also loose function in programs like `FILENAME` in `awk`.  For other to learn, its better to show the best way first.  If you like to show it with `cat`, post both and explain its only to show flow, and you should not use it.

Comment: @Jotne Done. I've changed formating too in order to _not_ hide the source file outside of the "code scrolling window"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the shell, don't use awk, don't use sed, don't use any other text processing tools. Use xsltproc or some other similar tool designed for working with xml.

With a properly constructed xml document with a single root node the following transform will do what you want when run as `xsltproc --stringparam SomeValue "$SomeVal" metadata.xsl metadata.xml`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="SomeValue"/>

    <!-- Whenever you match any node or any attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <!-- Copy the current node -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MissingValue">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($SomeValue)"/>
            <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am by no means an xslt expert so there may very well be better ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks. In my situation, however, I think I need to use BASH at some level. My BASH script parses other non-XML files to get the value of the variable `someVal` that I need to put in the `MissingValue` tag. I doubt `xsltproc` can read files in a custom format, but even if it could, I have so much existing code in BASH I'd rather not learn `xsltproc` AND translate my existing code.

I'm happy to try using `xsltprox`, howver. Do you know _how_ I could invoke `xsltproc` from my script so that it takes the value from BASH and puts it in the `MissingValue` tag?

Comment: @jvriesem xsltproc supports passing parameters in via the command line so that's a perfectly valid way to get the value in. I've even written the xsl to do that. The only issue is that your input xml document isn't "valid" for xslt since it doesn't have a single root element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
SomeVal=1234567890.0
awk '/<MissingValue>/ {$0=$0"\n    "v}1' v="$SomeVal" metadata.xml
<foo1>
    someData
</foo1>
<foo2>
    123.54
</foo2>
<MissingValue>
    1234567890.0

</MissingValue>
<foo3>
    1.0
</foo3>
```